# A question related to the rank of a free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am currently working on the following problem from Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*:

> **Exercise 4.4** Suppose $k$ is a field and let $R=k[t]/(t^2)$. Consider $p(x)=tx^{3}+tx^{2}-x^{2}-x\in R[x]$.
> I am interested in showing that $S:=R[x]/(p)$ is a free $R$-module of rank 2, but I am not sure how to proceed. So, any hint/help will be appreciated.

Also, there is a proposition in the same textbook which states: *Let $R$ be a ring $J\subset R[x]$ be an ideal in the polynomial ring in one variable over $R.$ Let $S:=R[x]/J$ and let $s$ be the image of $x$ in $S$. Then $S$ is a finitely generated free $R$-module if and only if $J$ can be generated by a monic polynomial. In this case $S$ has a basis of the form $1,s,\dots,s^{n-1}$.*

So, if we show that $S$ is a free module of rank $2$, doesn't that contradict the above proposition?

Thanks.

Comment: Then try to see if the ideal generated by $p(x)$ is not also generated by a monic polynomial of degree $2$. Since $R$ is not integral, things can be a little counter-intuitive. For instance, what happens when you multiply $p(x)$ by $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Since $t\in R$ is nilpotent, $tx-1$ is invertible in $R[x]$.